# Spring - login page to have terms and condition page (using Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc, checkbox, jspx

In my web application, I am using Spring MVC. I have the default login page that spring MVC uses. In my login page I need to have a checkbox. While logging in, the user must enable the checkbox and then click the 'LOGIN' button.
If he doesn't check the 'checkbox' a pop-up window should be displayed(with some error message).

I would like to implement this using javascript.

Can anyone please tell how to implement this?

This is my JSPX file. Sorry it is big

```
<div xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" xmlns:util="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/util" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.0">
  <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <spring:message code="security_login_title" var="title" htmlEscape="false" />
  <util:panel id="title" title="${title}">
    <c:if test="${not empty param.login_error}">
      <div class="errors">
        <p>
          <spring:message code="security_login_unsuccessful" />
          <c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}" />
          .
        </p>
      </div>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${empty param.login_error}">
      <p>
        <spring:message code="security_login_message" />
      </p>
    </c:if>
    <spring:url value="/resources/j_spring_security_check" var="form_url" />
    <form name="f" action="${fn:escapeXml(form_url)}" method="POST">
      <div>
        <label for="j_username">
          <spring:message code="security_login_form_name" />
        </label>
        <input id="j_username" type='text' name='j_username' style="width:150px" />
        <spring:message code="security_login_form_name_message" var="name_msg" htmlEscape="false" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
          <c:set var="sec_name_msg">
            <spring:escapeBody javaScriptEscape="true">${name_msg}</spring:escapeBody>
          </c:set>
          Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({elementId : "j_username", widgetType : "dijit.form.ValidationTextBox", widgetAttrs : {promptMessage: "${sec_name_msg}", required : true}})); 
        </script>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div>
        <label for="j_password">
          <spring:message code="security_login_form_password" />
        </label>
        <input id="j_password" type='password' name='j_password' style="width:150px" />
        <spring:message code="security_login_form_password_message" var="pwd_msg" htmlEscape="false" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
          <c:set var="sec_pwd_msg">
            <spring:escapeBody javaScriptEscape="true">${pwd_msg}</spring:escapeBody>
          </c:set>
          Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({elementId : "j_password", widgetType : "dijit.form.ValidationTextBox", widgetAttrs : {promptMessage: "${sec_pwd_msg}", required : true}})); 
        </script>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="submit">
        <script type="text/javascript">Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ValidateAllDecoration({elementId:'proceed', event:'onclick'}));</script>
        <spring:message code="button_submit" var="submit_label" htmlEscape="false" />
        <input id="proceed" type="submit" value="${fn:escapeXml(submit_label)}" />
        <spring:message code="button_reset" var="reset_label" htmlEscape="false" />
        <input id="reset" type="reset" value="${fn:escapeXml(reset_label)}" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </util:panel>
</div>
```

I have the following input.tagx file

```
<jsp:root xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.0">
  <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <jsp:directive.attribute name="id" type="java.lang.String" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" description="The identifier for this tag (do not change!)" />
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="field" type="java.lang.String" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" description="The field exposed from the form backing object" />
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="label" type="java.lang.String" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="The label used for this field, will default to a message bundle if not supplied" />
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="labelCode" type="java.lang.String" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="Key for label message bundle if label is not supplied" />
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="required" type="java.lang.Boolean" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="Indicates if this field is required (default false)" />
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="disabled" type="java.lang.Boolean" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="Specify if this field should be enabled" />
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="validationRegex" type="java.lang.String" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="Specify regular expression to be used for the validation of the input contents" />
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="validationMessageCode" type="java.lang.String" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="Specify the message (message property code) to be displayed if the regular expression validation fails" />
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="validationMessage" type="java.lang.String" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="Specify the message to be displayed if the regular expression validation fails" />
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="min" type="java.lang.String" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="Specify the minimum length of the input contents" />
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="max" type="java.lang.String" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="Specify the maximum length of the input contents" />
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="decimalMin" type="java.lang.String" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="Specify the minimum size of the input contents" />
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="decimalMax" type="java.lang.String" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="Specify the maximum size of the input contents" />
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="disableFormBinding" type="java.lang.Boolean" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="Set to true to disable Spring form binding" />
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="type" type="java.lang.String" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="Set field type (default 'text', or 'password')" />
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="render" type="java.lang.Boolean" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="Indicate if the contents of this tag and all enclosed tags should be rendered (default 'true')" />
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="z" type="java.lang.String" required="false" description="Used for checking if element has been modified (to recalculate simply provide empty string value)" />

  <c:if test="${empty render or render}">

    <c:if test="${empty type}">
      <c:set value="text" var="type" />
    </c:if>

    <c:if test="${empty disabled}">
      <c:set value="false" var="disabled" />
    </c:if>

    <c:if test="${empty label}">
      <c:if test="${empty labelCode}">
        <c:set var="labelCode" value="${fn:substringAfter(id,'_')}" />
      </c:if>
      <spring:message code="label_${fn:toLowerCase(labelCode)}" var="label" htmlEscape="false" />
    </c:if>

    <c:if test="${empty validationMessage}">
      <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${empty validationMessageCode}">
          <spring:message arguments="${fn:escapeXml(label)}" code="field_invalid" var="field_invalid" htmlEscape="false" />
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
          <spring:message arguments="${fn:escapeXml(label)}" code="${validationMessageCode}" var="field_invalid" htmlEscape="false" />
        </c:otherwise>
      </c:choose>
    </c:if>

    <c:if test="${empty required}">
      <c:set value="false" var="required" />
    </c:if>

    <c:set var="sec_field">
      <spring:escapeBody javaScriptEscape="true" >${field}</spring:escapeBody>
    </c:set>

    <div id="_${fn:escapeXml(id)}_id">
      <label for="_${sec_field}_id">
        <c:out value="${fn:escapeXml(label)}" />
        :
      </label>
      <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${disableFormBinding}">
          <input id="_${sec_field}_id" name="${sec_field}" type="${fn:escapeXml(type)}" />
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
          <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${type eq 'password'}">
              <form:password id="_${sec_field}_id" path="${sec_field}" disabled="${disabled}" />
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
              <form:input id="_${sec_field}_id" path="${sec_field}" disabled="${disabled}" />
            </c:otherwise>
          </c:choose>
          <br />
          <form:errors cssClass="errors" id="_${sec_field}_error_id" path="${sec_field}" />
        </c:otherwise>
      </c:choose>
      <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${required}">
          <spring:message code="field_required" var="field_required" htmlEscape="false" />
          <spring:message argumentSeparator="," arguments="${label},(${field_required})" code="field_simple_validation" var="field_validation" htmlEscape="false" />
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
          <spring:message argumentSeparator="," arguments="${label}, " code="field_simple_validation" var="field_validation" htmlEscape="false" />
        </c:otherwise>
      </c:choose>
      <c:set var="sec_field_validation">
        <spring:escapeBody javaScriptEscape="true">${field_validation}</spring:escapeBody>
      </c:set>
      <c:set var="sec_field_invalid">
        <spring:escapeBody javaScriptEscape="true" htmlEscape="true">${field_invalid}</spring:escapeBody>
      </c:set>
      <c:set var="sec_field_required">
        <spring:escapeBody javaScriptEscape="true">${field_required}</spring:escapeBody>
      </c:set>
      <c:set var="sec_validation_regex" value="" />
      <c:if test="${!empty validationRegex}">
        <c:set var="sec_validation_regex" value="regExp : '${validationRegex}', " />
      </c:if>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({elementId : '_${sec_field}_id', widgetType : 'dijit.form.ValidationTextBox', widgetAttrs : {promptMessage: '${sec_field_validation}', invalidMessage: '${sec_field_invalid}', required : ${required}, ${sec_validation_regex} missingMessage : '${sec_field_required}' }})); 
      </script>
    </div>
    <br />
  </c:if>
</jsp:root>
```

I have the following checkbox.tagx file

```
<jsp:root xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.0">
  <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <jsp:directive.attribute name="id" type="java.lang.String" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" description="The identifier for this tag (do not change!)" />
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="field" type="java.lang.String" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" description="The field exposed from the form backing object" />
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="label" type="java.lang.String" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="The label used for this field, will default to a message bundle if not supplied" />
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="disableFormBinding" type="java.lang.Boolean" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="Set to true to disable Spring form binding" />
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="render" type="java.lang.Boolean" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="Indicate if the contents of this tag and all enclosed tags should be rendered (default 'true')" />
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="z" type="java.lang.String" required="false" description="Used for checking if element has been modified (to recalculate simply provide empty string value)" />

  <c:if test="${empty render or render}">
    <c:if test="${empty label}">
      <spring:message code="label_${fn:toLowerCase(fn:substringAfter(id,'_'))}" var="label" htmlEscape="false" />
    </c:if>
    <c:set var="sec_field">
      <spring:escapeBody javaScriptEscape="true">${field}</spring:escapeBody>
    </c:set>

    <script type="text/javascript">dojo.require("dijit.form.CheckBox");</script>
    <div id="_${sec_id}_id">
      <label for="_${sec_field}_id">
        <c:out value="${fn:escapeXml(label)}" />:
      </label>
      <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${disableFormBinding}">
          <input id="_${sec_field}_id" name="${sec_field}" type="checkbox"/>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
          <form:checkbox id="_${sec_field}_id" path="${sec_field}"/>
        </c:otherwise>
      </c:choose>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({elementId : '_${sec_field}_id', widgetType : 'dijit.form.CheckBox', widgetAttrs : {}}));
      </script>
    </div>
    <br />
  </c:if>
</jsp:root>
```

Comment: I just want the user to check the checkbox. I dont need to do any validation at the backend.

Comment: What happens if the user has disabled javascript in their browser?  That would mean they could use the application without having accepted the terms and conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/rDjJH/1/) helps.

In your code:

```
<!-- add the id attribute to your form, to get it with JS -->
<form id="f" name="f" action="${fn:escapeXml(form_url)}" method="POST">
    ...
    <!-- add an input checkbox -->
    <input type="checkbox" id="terms" />
    ....
    <!-- in your input button add onclick attribute calling the JS function -->
    <input id="proceed" onclick="doSubmit()" type="submit" value="${fn:escapeXml(submit_label)}" />
    ...
</form>
```

And this is the JS function you need:

```
function doSubmit() {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("terms");
    if (!checkbox.checked) {
        alert("error message here!");
        return;
    }
    document.getElementById("f").submit();
}​
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Jelies, I just now added the code on top of which I need to implement the checkbox. Can you please check and let me know if you could help?

Comment: It's not correct, because you are not calling to `doSubmit()` and it's necessary!

Comment: are you sure the function is being called when you click the proceed button?

Comment: yes it is called. Can you please check this new question if possible? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664000/javascript-stop-proceeding-after-alert-message