# Javascript - stop proceeding after alert message

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, alert

In my web application, in the login page, I have a checkbox. After entering the username/password, if the user doesn't tick the checkbox (T&C), he should not be taken to the home page, and an alert error message will be shown.

I have tried the following code. But it is not working. That is, an alert message is shown. But the user is taken to the next page(home page). I tried returning false, but no luck.

Can anyone tell how to fix this?

```
function doSubmit() {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("terms");
    if (!checkbox.checked) {
        alert("error message here!");
        return;
    }
    document.getElementById("f").submit();
}​
```

I am calling doSubmit from

```
<input id="proceed" onclick="doSubmit()" type="submit" value="${fn:escapeXml(submit_label)}" />
```

Comment: how are you calling doSubmit()

Comment: @user1351052 Is `doSubmit` called in the submit event, a button click event, some other arbitrary call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the input type to **button** instead of **submit**, delegating the submit action to JS function:

```
<input id="proceed" onclick="doSubmit()" type="button" value="${fn:escapeXml(submit_label)}" />
```

Comment: For both checked (positive scenario) and unchecked(negative scenario) checkbox, the next page is not getting displayed :(

Comment: Have you set `id` attribute to "f" of your form?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `onclick` in input, try using the below in the form tag:

```
onsubmit="return doSubmit()"
```

And the js functions as:

```
function doSubmit() {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("terms");
    if (!checkbox.checked) {
        alert("error message here!");
        return false;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you submit your form, you should check the `checkbox`'s status, if it's not checked, prevent the from from submit. In jQuery, the following code does the tricks.

```
$(form).submit(function(e){
    if($(this).find("#terms").is('checked')){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('error messge goes here');
    }
}
```